# whats the problem of this code?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, chess

I wrote some code to move the king in chess game; can you tell me where is the problem of this code that king doesn't move? Thanks.

**EDITED2:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    PictureBox[,] pic = new PictureBox[8, 8];

private void pictureBox34_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

if (pictureBox34.Image == chess9.Properties.Resources.siyahsah2)

{

f();
}
}

public void picarray()
{
        pic[0, 0] = pictureBox54;
        pic[0, 1] = pictureBox64;
        pic[0, 2] = pictureBox48;
        pic[0, 3] = pictureBox42;
        pic[0, 4] = pictureBox34;
        pic[0, 5] = pictureBox26;
        pic[0, 6] = pictureBox18;
        pic[0, 7] = pictureBox8;
        pic[1, 0] = pictureBox1;
        pic[1, 1] = pictureBox2;
        pic[1, 2] = pictureBox3;
        pic[1, 3] = pictureBox4;
              .
              .///thats so long(64 arrays)
              .
 }

public void f()
{



        int x = 3;
        int y = 3;

       for (int i = 1; i < x; i++)
       {
            for (int j = 1; j < y; j++)
            {
                pic[i, j] = new PictureBox();

                pic[i, j] = pic[i + 1, j + 1];

                pic[i, j] = new PictureBox();
                pic[i, j].Image = Image.FromFile("pic/siyahsah2.jpg");

          }

}
}
```

Comment: To be honest, almost everything is wrong here like function names, using references of images to check if they're the same, illegal array indexes (i - 1, j -1) etc. etc.

Comment: This new version still doesn't make sense, what's the use of the picarray function? any why the strange array assignments in f()? the first one doesn't even do anything as it's overwritten by the second and even then it's going to mess up the whole array like that. Can you try to explain what the idea is? What you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: i try to implement movements of king piece in chess game.so what do you suggest?thanks

Comment: I understood as much, but why the hardcoded values like pic[0,4] and x = 3, y = 3 and pictureBox34 and such?

Comment: i think using pictureboxes is more easier than other,isnt it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you didn't define the return types correctly, as you don't have any return values at all anywhere in that code.

Let's see what the code might do...

The first problem is this line:

```
if (pictureBox34.Image == Image.FromFile("pic/siyahsah2.jpg"))
```

The `FromFile` method will create a new object, and as that object will never be the same object as the one stored in the picture box, the condition is always false and the method `f` is never called.

In the method `picarray` you are using the variable `pic`, but that won't be the same variable as the one used in the `f` method, as that variable is declared locally in that method,

In the `f` method you are declaring an array of picture boxes which you manipulate, but then you just exit the method without doing anything with the array, so the array just goes away and the result will never be visible anywhere.

As the array is newly created, it contains only null referecens, so copying them from one item to another in the array doesn't accomplish anything. You are also copying items from two positions into the same position, so the second copy will overwrite the first.

As the variables `i` and `j` are set to zero, `[i - 1, j - 1]` will try to access an item that is outside the array, which would give you an exception.

You are trying to store something in the `Image` property of one of the items in the array, but as all items in the array are null, there is no picture box that you can set the `Image` property of.

It's hard to tell what you are trying to do, but this information should at least help you to understand what the code doesn't do.

Comment: thanks so much,your answer is so clear.but i didnt understand your answer about array newly created and paragraph 3,paragraph 6 of your answer.thanks so so much,i edited my question

Comment: @arash: You are declaring the array variable inside the method, which means that the variable only exists within the method. You are creating a new array each time the method is called, so the content will not be retained from one call to the next. For that you would typically declare a variable in your form class, so that it survives as long as the form does. When you create an array of PictureBox, it will not automatically be filled with PictureBox objects, you have to assign one for each slot in the array.

Comment: @Guffa:i edited question and outed the pic[,] declaring from method,how is it now?last line of your comment mean i should took array for each picturebox?so i should take 64 picturebox?for example:pic[0,2]=picturebox3;.....?thanks so much

Comment: i edited again,i did almost everything you said,now whats the problem you think?thanks

Comment: @arash: You are getting close. The problem now is that inside the loop you are creating new picture boxes that you put in the array. Those picture boxes are not part of the form, so they will not show up. The array should remain the way that you set it up in `picarray`, you should not move around or replace items in the array, you should only change the `Image` property of the existing picture boxes. So, remove the first three lines inside the loop, and you should see something happen. From there you should be able to figure out how to adjust the code to make it do what you want.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (pictureBox34.Image == Image.FromFile("pic/siyahsah2.jpg"))
```

Do you know the implications of this line of code?

- Every time this statement is executed, a new instance is created, using the image stored on disk
- The comparison never evaluates to true, since the comparison is based on the equality of references, which obviously cannot be true for a newly created object

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to tell what you are trying to do in the overall code with this snippet but it doesnt look right, no.

The problem I see is that in `f()` you create the `PictureBox pic`, set some of its properties but then dont do anything with it. At the end of `f()` the method returns and `pic` is destroyed.

If this code actually compiles then from your use of `pix[]` in the `picarray()` method I would say you have a class level variable somewhere that is your game board. In that case you dont need the line:

```
PictureBox[,] pic = new PictureBox[8, 8];
```

in `f()` because its just creating a new empty board that exists only within `f()` rather than updating your real board.

Comment: thanks for your clear answer,now what should i do to update my real board with array?

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line

```
PictureBox[,] pic = new PictureBox[8, 8]; from the f() function
```

i think , you are again initilizing of pic array with new picture

Comment: This is...not the only thing wrong. You should provide more explanation as to how this will fix the problems that the asker is experiencing.

Comment: than why you don't pointed this out for answer provided by Jim also because his answer is alos incomplete. This seems , you are biased!!

Comment: No bias, and I didn't downvote. However, I feel that Jim's answer is more complete because it explains *why* and *how* that particular line of code is causing a problem. Understanding why bugs occur is important if we're ever going to learn how to fix them ourselves.

Comment: @Code Gray : Thanks , i will remember your comment in future answers!Thanks for pointing this out but i haven't edited my post becuase other ppls already written in their answers